# Android: make a post to a webservice every X minutes

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've  seen some people with this same issue, however my case is a little bit different. The app must call a web service every X minutes no matter what fragment or activity is currently open. However all the cases I've seen here they give an option that works while on the same activity.

Edit: most work as a background job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Firebase Jobdispatcher` to implement what you need

Refer [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)